# Не понятное значение в double

Tags: java

Нашёл в уроке такую строку:

```
double couts = 0.0f;
```

И не смог понять,что за значение такое  ставится в double?

**0.0f** или **0.7f**

Что это?

Простите за нубство =)

Comment: f обозначает float

Comment: то есть 0 это тип int, а 0f это уже float

Comment: Единственное, что хочется добавить, что для того, чтобы это было все-таки double, а не float нужно писать 0.0 без f;

Comment: @SilverIce: ну или `0d`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 ____________________________________________
| Примитивный тип  |  Значение по умолчанию  |  
|__________________|_________________________|                   
|boolean           |  false                  |   
|char              |  `\u0000` (null)        | 
|byte              |  (byte)0                |
|short             |  (short)0               |
|int               |  0                      |
|long              |  0L                     |
|float             |  0.0f                   |
|double            |  0.0d                   |
|__________________|_________________________|
```

Вот так, как то ;)

Answer (score 1):

это 0

Почитайте первые главы любого учебника, где описываются типы данных.